# Преобразование типа при записи в файл

Tags: c++

Исходные данные: Есть бинарный файл который читаем `ifstream in (FName, ifstream::binary);` . Есть структура содержащая поля типа char . `char a[8];`
Необходимо прочитать файл в струтктуру и вывести hex;. Делаю так

```
ifstream in (FName, ifstream::binary);

  in.read((char*)&X, sizeof X); //Читаем структуру
int len1=in.gcount();

ofstream fout(FName1);
 fout << "Поле=";
  for(int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
      fout<<setfill ('0')<<setw(2)<<hex<<(int)X.a[i];
  };
```

При выводе в страшем байте появляются лишнее ffffff.

Вопрос:Как избавиться от лишних символов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте приводить к типу unsigned char:

```
cout << static_cast<int>(*reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&a[i]));
```

Объяснение явления такое  - в *вашей реализации компилятора c++* char - знаковый тип, и когда вы кастуете его к `int`, вы получаете отрицательное число. А отрицательное число у вас кодируется в дополнительном коде, отсюда куча единичных бит.

Первое преобразование - жесткое приведения типа - мы просто заставляем компилятор рассматривать байты по этому адресу как тип `unsigned char` - к беззнаковому символьному той же размерности.

Для пущей жесткости, можно где-то в программе написать:

```
static_assert(sizeof(char)==sizeof(unsigned char),"wrong signed/unsigned char size!");
```

Второе преобразование - фактически, создается новая анонимная переменная  типа `int`, в которую записывается значение, полученное на первом шаге.

Приведение к типу `int` нужно для того, чтобы `iostream` соизволил интерпретировать выводимое как число, а не как символ.

Comment: _"char - знаковый тип"_ - вот уж не факт.

Comment: размеры типов не меняются от наличия или отсутствия знаковости. Да и `reinterpret_cast` ваш не сработает, даже если `shar` заменить на `char`.

Comment: @alexolut это если компилятор дружит со стандартом. Разумеется, проверка излишняя, но так как она делается во время компиляции - не вижу особых проблем ее оставить

Comment: Есть некоторые базовые вещи, с которыми должны дружить все c++ компиляторы, независимо от следования Стандарту. Можете привести пример где размер меняется от знаковости или это является расширением компилятора?

Comment: В касте по-прежнему не хватает `&` и `*`.